# How do you get current row and access columns using VBA in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in an Excel spreadsheet. Let say it has two columns "Id" and "Name". Using VBA, I want to use the double click event on the worksheet to capture the "Id" and the "Name" in the current row.

I use the Intersect function to figure out if the double click occurred in the table I'm interested in, but I don't know how to access the row data using table column names.

i.e.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
   Dim user_rge as Range
   Set user_rge = Me.Worksheets("Data").Range("Users")
   If Not Intersects(user_rge, target) is Nothing Then
        Dim id as Integer
        Dim name as String
        ` What goes in here?
   End
End Sub
```

Comment: This isn't a table. Its a named range.

Comment: It is a table. If I select a cell in the sheet, I can access all of the table tools. I also can reference other columns in the table using Users[Id], etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I eneded up doing. In this example, "Main" is the worksheet which has the table on it. The name of the table is "TableName", which has columns "columnXXXX", "columnYYYY" and "columnZZZZ"

I could probably create a helper function called, TableLookupByRange(tablename, columnname, range), where you could pass in the name of the table, the name of the column and a range which containg a cell anywhere in the row you want to do the lookup. Which would clean up the code as well.

```
Dim table_lo as ListObject
Dim main_ws as Worksheet
Set main_ws = Me.Worksheets("Main")
Set table_lo = main_ws.ListObjects("TableName")

rownum = target.Row - 1
columnXXXX_colnum = table_lo.ListColumns("columnXXXX").index
columnYYYY_colnum = table_lo.ListColumns("columnYYYY").index
columnZZZZ_colnum = table_lo.ListColumns("columnZZZZ").index

Dim columnXXXX As String
Dim columnYYYY As String
Dim columnZZZZ As Double

columnXXXX = trades_rge.Cells(rownum, columnXXXX_colnum).Value
columnYYYY = UCase(trades_rge.Cells(rownum, columnYYYY_colnum).Value)
columnZZZZ = trades_rge.Cells(rownum, columnZZZZ_colnum).Value
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the row using `ActiveCell.Row`. For columns, you will have to check whether user clicked on ID or Name by comparing it with the source range.

i.e.

```
If ActiveCell.Column = users_rge.Columns(1) Then
   ID = ActiveCell.Value
   Name = ActiveCell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value
Else
   Name = ActiveCell.Value
   ID = ActiveCell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Value
End If
```

Note: I haven't tried this code, am writing this from what I have in mind.

Answer (score -1):

Try this as you are almost there with your code: use [Range.Columns Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837125.aspx) to compare Target against user_range columns 1 and 2.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
   Dim id as Integer
   Dim name as String
   Dim user_rge as Range

   Set user_rge = Me.Worksheets("Data").Range("Users")
   If Not Intersects(user_rge, target) is Nothing Then
      Select Case Target.Column
         Case user_rge.Columns(1)
              id = Target.Offset(0,0).Value
              name = Target.Offset(0,1).Value   
         Case user_rge.Columns(2)             
              id = Target.Offset(0,-1).Value
              name = Target.Offset(0,0).Value     
      End Select
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you look at the question, I'm trying to avoid having to avoid using  fixed column number references. I'd like to use code that looks something like:

Dim id as Int
id = GetTableData("Users", "Id",  target)
Where target is any cell in the row.